# I installed Mantis bug tool for testing but mails is not coming and sending also, What I have to do now?

Tags: mantis

I installed Mantis bug tool for testing but mails is not coming and sending also, What I have to do now?

Please find my code below:

```
$g_enable_email_notification=ON;    
$g_phpMailer_method= PHPMAILER_METHOD_SMTP;    
$g_smtp_host='smtp.gmail.com';   
$g_smtp_username= '********@gmail.com';   
$g_smtp_password= '*******';   
$g_smtp_connection_mode='tls';   
$g_smtp_port=587;   
$g_administrator_email='*******@office.com';    
$g_webmaster_email='******@office.com';  
$g_from_email='*****@gmail.com';    
$g_return_path_email='*******@gmail.com';    
$g_from_name='Mantis Bug Tracker';   
$g_email_receive_own=ON;    
$g_email_send_using_cronjob=ON;
```

Comment: Check your server logs. Google may require you to verify the connection before sending an email through it's SMTP. Note that Google SMTP also has a rate limit.

Comment: I din't got what you told, Please provide any solution if you have..